# Monitor PPPOE connection with vnstat

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring, vnstat

I've try

```
vahid@DEMON:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  
...

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
...

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
...

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  
...

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  
...
```

Then

```
vahid@DEMON:~$ vnstat -i ppp0
```

and got this error:`Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/ppp0".`
Then

```
vahid@DEMON:~$ vnstat -u  -i ppp0
```

And got these error: `Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/ppp0".
Error: Unable to write database "/var/lib/vnstat/ppp0".`

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `vnstat -u` you will need to use `sudo`

so do the below command with `sudo`

```
 sudo vnstat -u  -i ppp0
```

If all goes ok it should create a database.

Now configure `/etc/vnstat.conf` to monitor ppp0 interface

```
Interface "ppp0"
```

and then restart vnstat

```
/etc/init.d/vnstat restart
```